When do I need to use act() when tests cause react state updates
I'm using vitest and @testing-library/react. Both tests pass, but the 2nd one shows a warning to use act(). Clicking on the foo and bar buttons causes a react state update, but it seems only when triggering setBaz inside the timeout does it complain.
export function Foo() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('');
  const [bar, setBar] = useState('');
  const [baz, setBaz] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bar) setTimeout(() => setBaz('baz'), 5000);
  }, [bar]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setFoo('foo')}>Foo: {foo}</button>
      <button onClick={() => setBar('bar')}>Bar: {bar}</button>
      <div>Baz: {baz}</div>
    </>
  );
}

test('should work', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  render(<Foo />);

  const foo = screen.getByText(/Foo:/);
  await user.click(foo);

  expect(foo.innerHTML).toEqual('Foo: foo');
});

/*
  Warning: An update to Foo inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
*/
test('should work', async () => {
  vi.useFakeTimers({ shouldAdvanceTime: true });
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  render(<Foo />);

  const bar = screen.getByText(/Bar:/);
  await user.click(bar);

  vi.advanceTimersByTime(5000);

  await waitFor(() => {
    const baz = screen.getByText(/Baz:/);
    expect(baz.innerHTML).toEqual('Baz: baz');
  });
});

If I wrap the advance advanceTimersByTime in act(() => vi.advanceTimersByTime(5000)) then that fixes the warning.

Using act, while not always necessary is good practice when updating state or testing rendered components, since it "makes your test run closer to how React works in the browser" (docs) by making sure that rendering happens before any assertions.
